# want a date and time also conversion in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm getting date with format using following expression

`$("#datepicker").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd ");`

I want `time` also with `date`.

> please guide me for conversion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **no** *default approach to add time* with default datepicker of jQuery UI.

So move to [**dateTimepicker**](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you might need [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) and format of your jquery would be,

```
var timeAndDate = moment().format("dddd, MMMM Do, YYYY, h:mm:ss A");

$('#datepicker').append(timeAndDate);
```